# python execute synchronous windows commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess, command-prompt

I want to execute multiple commands(command prompt) in python such that I can use output of one command as an input to the next command. And also, the commands are to be run in the same command prompt. Is there any way that is possible in python?
I know that commands can be run using subprocess.Popen().
Consider the following script:

```
import subprocess
#let the command be cmd1
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

proc.stdin.write(cmd1)
proc.stdin.close()
print(proc.stdout.read())
```

This is useful when want to execute multiple commands. But I also want to use the output of one command as an input to the next command.

> Note: I want to execute the python script in windows 10

Comment: Via `subprocess.Popen`, you have control over the initial execution environment of each child process (e.g. inherited console, standard I/O, working directory, environment variables) and know precisely when a command has terminated. What does using the same CMD shell accomplish that's worth the extra work and headaches this entails?

Comment: Anyway, don't close `proc.stdin`; use `universal_newlines=True`  to ensure each line ends with `"\r\n"`; and use separate threads to read by line from `proc.stdout` and `proc.stderr`. Queue the output with timestamps so you can merge the stdout and stderr results correctly and know what's in response to a given input command.